# How to add a property to an object using the ['key'] notation?

Tags: javascript

JavaScript documentations states that in order to add a property to an existing object you could do the following.

```
data["property"] = value;
```

or

```
data.property = value;
```

In my case, I'm trying to convert my model ID (received by the server) to string before adding it, such as:

```
data.model[id.toString()] = false;
```

But I get the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property '1' of undefined
```

I initially though that it was because you couldn't use an alphanumeric string or some kind of weird limitation, so I tried prefixing my ID with a letter, such as:

```
var id = 'k' + id.toString();
```

Still doesn't work!  But when I use Chrome's Console panel and do it manually, such as:

```
var data = {};
var data['1'] = false;
```

That works, so what am I doing wrong?

What is the official name for `data.['key'] = value;` operations anyway?  It would help knowing when trying to Google for help.

---

**Update 1**: Ok, it seems that it may be due to the following:

```
var data = localStorage.getItem('model.state');
```

When I change it to:

```
var data = {};
```

It suddenly started to work!

---

**Update 2**: I see what I'm doing wrong (but still not sure why it was giving me an 'undefined' error... anyone?).

I did the following:

```
var data = localStorage.getItem('model.state');
if (data) data = JSON.parse(data);
```

And it started to work as expected.  Sorry about that... thanks for the help everyone!

Comment: `data.model` doesn't seem to be defined. You have to initialize it as an object before you can read or assign properties to it.

Comment: *"What is the official name for data.['key'] = value; operations anyway?"* It's called **bracket notation**: http://es5.github.io/#x11.2.1 (at least the `foo[...]` part. Overall it's a *simple assignment expression* http://es5.github.io/#x11.13.1).

Comment: FYI, you don't need `data.model[id.toString()]`. Just do `data.model[id]` since all properties are automatically converted `toString()`. Even if the `toString()` is custom, it'll get invoked.

Comment: `localStorage` can only store strings. If you encoded the data as JSON and stored it, you have to decode it again.

Comment: @FelixKling Yes, all my local storage are JSON strings.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You get this error because `data.model` is not defined. In order to prevent the thrown error you can use:

```
data.model = data.model || {};
data.model[id.toString()] = false;
```

This is the short version of:

```
if (!data.model) {
  data.model = {};
}
data.model[id.toString()] = false;
```

Comment: But I do an `if (!data) data = {};` and `if (!data.model) data.model = {};` immediately before trying to add properties.  I'll go back and double check what's going on... thanks!

Comment: @Jeach: Apparently you are not, otherwise you wouldn't get that error. http://jsfiddle.net/zhWLS/